# when to use AJAX and when not to use AJAX in web application

Tags: ajax, web-applications

We have web applications [elgifto.com](http://www.elgifto.com/), [roadbrake.com](http://www.roadbrake.com/) in which we used AJAX at many places, especially to update major portions of a page. All the important functionality of [elgifto.com](http://www.elgifto.com/) was implemented using AJAX. Now we realize a few issues due to AJAX implementation.

1. All the content implemented using
   AJAX is not available to the SEO
   bots and it is hurting the page rank
   of our site.
2. Users will not be able to bookmark
   some of the pages as they are always
   available through AJAX.
3. When we want to direct the user from
   one page through an anchor link to
   another page having AJAX, we find it
   difficult.

So now we are thinking of removing AJAX for these pages and use it only for small functionality such as something similar to marking a question as favorite in SO. So before going ahead and removing, we want to know expert's opinion on this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no problem with AJAX. Your problem is _not_ using progressive enhancement. make sure the website works without JavaScript, then _enhance_ it with JavaScript and ajax.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not "AJAX" per se, but your implementation of it. Just as a for instance, you can fix the 'bookmark' problem like google maps does it: provide a generated link for each state of your webapp.

SEO can befixed by supplying various of these state-links to the crawlers, either organically trough links in your site, or by supplying a list (sitemap).

If you implement 2, you can fix 1 and 3 with those links.

In the end you must figure out if the effort is worth it, and if you are not overusing AJAX ofcourse, but the statements you've made are not set in stone at all.

Comment: we thought of implementing the sitemap, but it helps only in a few situations. In a few cases, even site map is not going to help as the pages under consideration are driven by user interaction. So you cannot keep link to any page as page content is driven by user actions. You have made very good points. thanks.

Comment: I always go by, but am aware that this might not be true for all sites, the following: If it should be in the google index, it should and can be linkable, and it should and can be in the sitemap. If it is technically impossible to make a link (e.g. a drawing made in flash on the screen or somtehing like that) it probably doesn't belong in the google index anyway.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm costantly developing ajax based websites, with no problems for SEO at all. You just have to use it in the best possible way.

For example, I have a website with normal links pointing to normal webpages (PHP pages), this for normal navigation if a user doesn't have JS enabled. But if a user has JS enabled, a script will change the links behavior, only fetching the content of the page needed.

This way you still have phisycal separated webpages with all their content, which will be indexed as normal.